# How to control the rotation of particles following a curve guide

Tags: particles, force-fields

I want to achieve a line of ants walking on a curved surface. I decided to use a particles system set to emitter, with a curve guide to force them along a path.
I set the initial rotation of the particles manually by enabling "object rotation".

[image]

[image]

I want them to rotate according to the curve, instead they are maintaining their initial rotation.
I think this is what I'm looking for:

> Curve Guide: If you use a Curve Guide and want the particles to follow the curve, you have to set Angular Velocity to Spin and leave the rotation on Constant (i.e. do not turn on Dynamic). Curve Follow does not work for particles.
> https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/physics/particles/emitter/rotation.html#angular-velocity

But in the current version of blender (3.0.1) the options under angular velocity are different and there is no "Spin".

In this video (one year old) the guy seems to reach the result I'm looking for by enabling "dynamic" (the opposite of what the documentation says!)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0Zfjdf21X0&t=1435s

EDIT:
I've made big progress, it's almost working, but still there is something weird, so i decided to edit the question and add an example file:

https://easyupload.io/4b8kuz

In the 001 collection I set up the particles system and the curve guide, then I enabled "dynamic" and the particles start rotating the way I want:

[image]

But I want them to stick to the path since they are "walking" on a surface. I found two way to do that, by resizing the radius of the curve (collection 002), or by changing the "clamping" and "shape" of the force guide (collection 003).
They seem to bring to the same result, they clamp correctly to the curve, but the rotation is now messed. The particles seem to born with their rotation and then been "forced" by something:

[image]

Now if I go back in the particle setting I can kind of force the rotation by giving them some initial velocity and changing the "orientation axis" and correcting the phase. (collection 004)

[image][image]

Job almost done.
The problem is that if you look carefully at the motion, the particles are kind of glitching during the path, witch isn't great.

Was this the correct way? Can I do better?

Comment: in your result...apply rotation to circle.003 ...is this what you want?